# SSAS - Category Dimension - Unknown Member

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, sql-server-2012, dimensional-modeling

I have an issue with getting my dimension set up properly.  Basically I have a fact table that holds details on events.   Each event can be categorized, but at different levels.  I have a category dimension that holds all the categories, subcategories.   There are three levels of categories.  Some categories have subcategories while others do not.

When I'm browsing the dimension I get drill downs for each item but the drill-downs sometimes end up displaying blank items(blue circle, no text).

So I guess I have a category dimension that is holding categories of different granularity.

I have been playing around with the settings for NULL processing and UnknownMember without really understanding fully how it affects things.

Perhaps someone out there can give me a few tips or advice on the issue.

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a ragged hierarchy.  The simplest solution is that if a node is null, copy it's parent key / caption down to it.

Comment: Ok So I think I'm making some progress ... I replaced the category table in the DSV with a named query table to replace the NULLs with the parent node values.  I set the MDX Compatibility mode to 2, and I set the HideMemberIf property of the children in the hierarchy to ParentName.   Now when I browse the dimension with the built-in browser tab the hierarchy appears correct.  BUT when I create a report, the entire hierarchy is not shown if any of the members were hidden.  So only the rows that has data for the full depth of the hierarchy is shown.  The rest are not shown.

Comment: If you didn't hide levels that were replicated from their parents because they were null, would the users complain / get confused?  Maybe if you used N/A as the caption rather than the parent name (but keeping the key of the parent - some reporting tools require complete uniqueness in the entire hierarchy, not just at one level).

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate `Ragged Hierarchies` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365406.aspx.  There are several options for a given level on hierarchy for the HideMemberIf property.

Comment: I set the MDX Compatibility mode to 2 and changed the HideMemberIf property for the child levels in the hierarchy to the various options.  Unfortunately instead of hiding the blank values it simply does not show the entire hierarchy for those that do not have the full 3 level deep hierarchy.   Items that only go down one level or two aren't displaying.   I'll continue researching but if someone here has an idea let me know.  Thanks.